# error in my mysql query

Tags: mysql, join

i have a query that fetches  data's from differant tables

```
SELECT p.USER_NAME,count(*) as total, pi.UpdatedDate FROM purchase p JOIN purchasedissues pi on pi.PurchaseId=p.PURCHASE_ID WHERE pi.UpdatedDate>DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND p.PURCHASE_DATE=CURDATE() AND p.USER_NAME NOT IN (SELECT username from tbl_test_user) GROUP BY p.USER_NAME having count(*)>2
```

but i got an error that

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT p.USER_NAME,count(*) as total, pi.UpdatedDate FROM
>   purchase p JOIN pur' at line 1

i can't figure it. please any one help me
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your query is ok. The error is indicating that it is near your `SELECT p.USER_NAME,...`. This usually happens when you are executing multiple query without terminating it. Ex,

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
SELECT p.USER_NAME,count(*) as total, pi.UpdatedDate FROM purchase....
```

so to correct it, just add a delimiter (*usually if not change, it's semi-colon*) to end your first query

```
SELECT * FROM tableName; -- <== this one
SELECT p.USER_NAME,count(*) as total, pi.UpdatedDate FROM purchase....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query! not sure if it works as I don't have the environment set in my machine but it may give you an essence to test it :)

```
SELECT p.USER_NAME,count(*) as total FROM purchase p JOIN purchasedissues pi on pi.PurchaseId=p.PURCHASE_ID WHERE pi.UpdatedDate>DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND p.PURCHASE_DATE=CURDATE() AND p.USER_NAME NOT IN (SELECT username from tbl_test_user) GROUP BY p.USER_NAME  having total > 2
```